# How do I generate C# classes from an XSD file with a lot of dependencies?

Tags: c#, xsd, xsd.exe

I'm new to both XSD files and the `XSD.exe` tool. I'm trying to generate C# classes from a set of XSD files. One of the files has got an `include` tag for each of the others, some of which have got `import` tags for other schemas that are available online.

When I try to generate the classes with `XSD.exe`, I get multiple warnings and the schema validation fails.
I won't go into the details of the original problem, as there are many files and many different warnings.

To figure out where I'm going wrong, I created a mock MWE, consisting of 4 files, included at the bottom.

When I run `xsd /c main.xsd importfile.xsd`, the classes are generated as expected.
Including the included file in the command (`xsd /c main.xsd includefile.xsd importfile.xsd`) makes no difference. Omitting the imported file causes the class generation to fail with missing declaration warning: `Type 'http://mock.namespace.com/country:CountryType' is not declared.` and `Type 'http://mock.namespace.com/country:ContinentType' is not declared.`.

I created the `maingml.xsd` file to test importing a file from a URL, removing the `includefile.xsd` and `importfile.xsd` dependencies. This is one of the schemas present in my original problem, and I wanted to see if I could successfully use some of its content in my test schema.
Unfortunately, the class generation failed with a missing declaration warning: `Type 'http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2:CodeType' is not declared.`.
Downloading the GML namespace files made no difference, and changing the `import`'s `schemaLocation` to `"gml.xsd"` starts producing a large amount of warnings - too large to include here. In fact, those are the warnings that are causing my original problem.

From my experiment I concluded that, for `XSD.exe` to work, I need to include in the command the names of files that are imported. I'm not sure how that works when the files are being imported from a given URL, however. Can I then ommit the file name in the `XSD.exe` command? Do I have to download those files and include their names in the command?
I have tried multiple scenarios in my original problem and none have worked. Among several different tries I have:

- Downloaded every file that's a dependency of some other file (67 files in total) and included all of their names in the command
- Included in the command only the names of the "root" files (the ones that include, directly or indirectly, every other file in their namespace)
- Changed every `import` tag's `schemaLocation` attribute to the local files that I had downloaded, and tried different file name combinations in the command again.

Is my conclusion wrong? What am I overlooking?

I'm open to any sort of input you can give me, including general XSD knowledge. I really do need to find a solution for my issue, though, so that's my priority.

`main.xsd`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:test="http://mock.namespace.com/test" targetNamespace="http://mock.namespace.com/test" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <include schemaLocation="includefile.xsd" />

    <element name="information" type="test:InfoType" />

    <complexType name="InfoType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="name" type="string" />
            <element name="age" type="int"/>
            <element name="code" type="test:CodeType" />
            <element name="origin" type="test:OriginType" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

</schema>
```

`maingml.xsd`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:test="http://mock.namespace.com/test" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" targetNamespace="http://mock.namespace.com/test" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd" />

    <element name="information" type="test:InfoType" />

    <complexType name="InfoType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="name" type="string" />
            <element name="age" type="int"/>
            <element name="code" type="gml:CodeType" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

</schema>
```

`includefile.xsd`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:test="http://mock.namespace.com/test" xmlns:country="http://mock.namespace.com/country" targetNamespace="http://mock.namespace.com/test" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <import namespace="http://mock.namespace.com/country" schemaLocation="importfile.xsd" />

    <element name="code" type="test:CodeType" />
    <element name="origin" type="test:OriginType" />

    <complexType name="CodeType">
        <simpleContent>
            <extension base="string">
                <attribute name="codeSpace" type="anyURI"/>
            </extension>
        </simpleContent>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="OriginType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="country" type="country:CountryType" />
            <element name="continent" type="country:ContinentType" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

</schema>
```

`importfile.xsd`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:country="http://mock.namespace.com/country" targetNamespace="http://mock.namespace.com/country" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <element name="country" type="country:CountryType" />

    <complexType name="CountryType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="country" type="string" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="ContinentType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="continent" type="string" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

</schema>
```

Comment: Since it has a schemaLocation, would it not be an idea to manually retrieve the file and add it to the deserializer?

Comment: @FreekW. I tried that already. I tried downloading only `gml.xsd`, only `basicTypes.xsd` (the file that actually contains the type I use in `maingml.xsd`), and all of the GML namespace files. I tried keeping the original `schemaLocation` values, and I tried replacing them with the local files on my computer.

Comment: I really haven't look at all the xsd above.  Normally the is a main xsd and the main schema has user defined types.  So you probably have to edit the main schema to add the user defined types (or add the user defined type into the classes).

Comment: @jdweng Do you mean I should flatten my set of schemas belonging to the same namespace as my main schema into just one main file, which contains every definition in that namespace? I'll try that, though I don't see how that would affect the problems with the imported schemas.

Comment: @jdweng I tried that. Flattening `main.xsd`, `includefile.xsd`, and `importfile.xsd` into one main schema had no effect on the result. As for `maingml.xsd`, where the issues arise, my definitions are already in that one file. The problem is with the imported schema, `gml.xsd`.

Comment: First you need to include all child schema namespaces in main schema. The add missing types into the main schema that are in the child.  You only have to add the root type of the children.  The main schema should have a place to add user types so the main schema doesn't give an error where the children are placed.  Then when you run xsd.exe on main schema the children should be included.

Comment: @jdweng If I understand you correctly, I need to add a tag for each of the types defined in the imported schemas, to the main schema. So, if a child has `<complexType name="AbstractGMLType" abstract="true"><sequence><group ref="gml:StandardObjectProperties"/></sequence><attribute ref="gml:id"/></complexType>`, I add `<complexType name="AbstractGMLType" />` to the main schema. Is that correct?

Comment: @jdweng * I add `<complexType name="gml:AbstractGMLType" />` to the main schema. I forgot the namespace prefix.

Comment: In theory Yes.  Does it work?

Comment: @jdweng I haven't tried it yet. There are _a lot_ of types defined across almost 100 schemas, and I won't have time to give it a go today. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @jdweng I finally got around to trying your suggestion. It didn't work. Aside from the warnings I was already getting, I got `Invalid 'name' attribute value 'gml:AbstractGMLType': 'The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, at position 3 within the name, cannot be included in a name.'.`, for each of the 2291 XSD components I'm including/importing. I don't know how else to reference the namespace.

Comment: I know what is causing the 0x3A error.  It is a colon.  On following line you are missing a namespace.  It should be something like xlmns:abc, but you are missing the abc in a few places in the posting above   : <import xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />

Comment: @jdweng That import tag makes the document invalid. `xmlns` doesn't seem to be a valid attribute. I have also generated classes from a few test schemas and I didn't import the XML schema in those. I understood the warning I posted before to mean that I can't include a colon in a name, which is to say `<complexType name="gml:AbstractGMLType" />` isn't a valid tag, because of the `gml` prefix being included in the name.

Comment: Do you still need any question answered?  You can validate XML (or schema) and edit XML in VS.  Use menu : Project : Add Existing Item : Xml File.  The paste xml into the window.  Error will show up in Error List like any compiler errors.

Comment: @jdweng The problem persists. I'm just not sure whether it's an issue with the GML schemas themselves, or with my ineptitude with XSD files. I've been using VS Code to edit the schemas and try to locate the source(s) of the problem, but to no avail.

Comment: Once you paste xml into VS you can click on schema URL which will bring up schema in VS.

Comment: You may be using an older version of a schema that doesn't support your options. There is usually a main URL webpage that you can go to with a browser to find all version.  It is a parent of the actual URL schema URL.

Comment: @jdweng I have got the schemas. I'm trying to generate classes based on those schemas.

Comment: You can paste the schema into VS as I described above to check for errors, also check for newer version of schema.

Comment: @jdweng As far as I'm aware, I've got the most recent schemas. In any case, they've got tdeclarations/definitions for the components used elsewhere in the schemas.

Comment: @jdweng I will see if VS finds more recent versions. Thank you.

Comment: @jdweng I'm afraid I couldn't find a way to find newer versions of a schema in VS, and Google wasn't helpful. How would I go about doing it? I'm almost positive that isn't the problem, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Usually I use the base URL.  Found following : http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/

Comment: @jdweng Right. Based on that, I do have the most recent schemas containing the relevant components.

Comment: Is the xml calling the same latest?

Comment: @jdweng There were a few instances of schemas importing older versions of GCO (one of the GML dependencies), while others imported the newer one. I checked that the newer version has the required components and changed the imports. I think I'm using the newest versions for the rest (it's hard to be sure, as the dependency tree is complex). Regardless, aside from possible incompatibilities between different versions of the same schema (the reason I changed the old GCO references), using an older version of a schema should work, given that the schema importing it is compatible with it, right?

Comment: Yes.  As long as the xml is compatible with the schema you are ok.  If you have a new xml with features not supported by older schema you have an issue.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not working with XML files yet (aside from the schemas, which are technically also XML files), I'm just trying to generate classes from these schemas. But that's good to know, as I will probably have to generate XML based on some schemas.

Comment: Did the newer schema fix the 0x3a error?  If you are still getting 0x3a I would try older schema.

Comment: @jdweng I couldn't find any newer versions of those schemas. I got the impression that error is due to me putting the namespace prefixes in the component names, as that is the code for a colon. I'm trying a different approach now, which may eliminate my issues. I'll post an update if that's the case.

Comment: @jdweng I ended up creating a schema for each of the required namespaces, manually, with only the required components. I couldn't figure out where the problem with the schemas lies, but I avoided it this way and generated the classes successfully. Thank you for the suggestions!